# Sveltekit prerender complex dynamic routes

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Is it possible to prerender multiple components into a single page with this kind of dynamic routes? i do not manage to get it done, it builds as a CSR page.
I have /src/routes/articles/articles.json:
`{ "title": ..., "subtitle": ..., "content": "name-of-component, "cover": "/images/articles/image", "author": "@author", "slug": ..., }, { "title": ..., "subtitle": ..., "content": "name-of-component, "cover": "/images/articles/image", "author": "@author", "slug": ..., },...`

then in /src/routes/articles/content/ i write each article in an svelte file so i can style each different, the name of each is name-of-component.svelte

i also have /src/routes/articles/[slug]/+page.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let data;
    import WIP from "$lib/icons/WIP.svelte";

    let wip;
    let article = data.props.article;
    let content = data.props.content;
    let twitterUrl = `https://twitter.com/${article.author}`;
    if (article.content === "wip") {
        wip = true;
    }
</script>
<div class="article">
    <div class="header">
        <a class="author author2" href={twitterUrl} target="_blank"
            >{article.author}</a
        >
        <img
            srcset="{article.cover}-small.webp 300w, 
        {article.cover}-mid.webp 500w, 
        {article.cover}-big.webp 700w"
            sizes="(max-width: 600px) 300px, 
       (max-width: 900px) 500px, 
       700px"
            alt={article.title}
        />
        <div class="header-title">
            <h1>{article.title}</h1>
            <h2>{article.subtitle}</h2>
            <a class="author author1" href={twitterUrl} target="_blank"
                >{article.author}</a
            >
        </div>
    </div>
    {#if wip}
        <WIP />
    {:else}
        <div class="content">
            <svelte:component this={content} />
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>
```

along with /src/routes/articles/[slug]/+page.js:

```
import articles from "../articles.json";

export async function load({ params }) {
    const article = articles.find((article) => article.slug === params.slug);
    let contentComponent;
    if (article.content === 'wip') {
        contentComponent = 'wip'
    } else {
        contentComponent = await import(`../content/${article.content}.svelte`);
    }
    return {
        props: {
            article,
            content: contentComponent.default,
        },
    };
}

export const prerender = true;
```

These articles are rendered on the landing page, src/routes/+page.svelte:

```
<script>
    import articles from "./articles/articles.json";
    import CoverLeft from "$lib/components/CoverLeft.svelte";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let firstBatch = articles.slice(0, 4);
    let secondBatch = articles.slice(4, 8);

    let observer;
    let isSecondCoverVisible = false;

    onMount(() => {
        observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    isSecondCoverVisible = true;
                }
            });
        });

        const secondCover = document.querySelector("#secondCover");
        observer.observe(secondCover);
    });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <CoverLeft articles={firstBatch} />
    <hr />
    <div id="secondCover">
        {#if isSecondCoverVisible}
            <CoverLeft articles={secondBatch} />
        {/if}
    </div>
</div>
```

being src/lib/component/CoverLeft.svelte:

```
<script>
    export let articles;

    let mainArticle = articles[0];
    let columnArticles = articles.slice(1);
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="cover">
        <a href="/articles/{mainArticle.slug}">
            <h1>{mainArticle.title}</h1>
            <h2>{mainArticle.subtitle}</h2>
            <img
                srcset="{mainArticle.cover}-small.webp 300w, 
                        {mainArticle.cover}-mid.webp 500w, 
                        {mainArticle.cover}-big.webp 700w"
                sizes="(max-width: 600px) 300px, 
                       (max-width: 900px) 500px, 
                       700px"
                alt={mainArticle.title}
            />
            <p class="author">{mainArticle.author}</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        {#each columnArticles as article}
            <div class="border-box">
                <a href="/articles/{article.slug}" data-sveltekit-preload-data>
                    <div class="article-item">
                        {#if article.cover}
                            <img
                                srcset="{article.cover}-small.webp 300w, 
                                        {article.cover}-mid.webp 500w, 
                                        {article.cover}-big.webp 700w"
                                sizes="(max-width: 600px) 300px, 
                                       (max-width: 900px) 500px, 
                                       700px"
                                alt={article.title}
                            />
                        {/if}
                        <div class="column-header">
                            <h1>{article.title}</h1>
                            <p class="author">{article.author}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

My svelte.config.js:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static'
import articles from './src/routes/articles/articles.json' assert { type: 'json' };

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
        }),
        prerender: {
            crawl: true,
            entries: [
                '/',
                ...articles.map(article => `/articles/${article.slug}`)
            ]
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

also src/routes/+layout.js:

```
export const prerender = true;
export const ssr = false;
```

My main +page.svelte is displayed within a +layout.svelte along with Header.svelte and Footer.svelte.

I know i might seem an odd strategy. I wanted to be able to create SSG + CSR with Sveltekit without a CMS and facilitate the updating of the articles. Build process does not return any error but the output is not prerendered.